# What does "Is E8C Device " in Huawei's iManager U2000 mean?

Tags: fiber, ont

I wonder what this "Is E8C Device" in the Screenshot added means it must be a Shortform or something like that but i seem to find litteraly nothing about E8C in conjunction with Huawei ONT's.

The Screenshot is as the Titel tells from Huawei's iManager U2000.

[image]

Comment: I would check their doc, or ask them directly on their contact form, or maybe twitter if they are online

Comment: the problem with this solution is we don't have it from Huawei directly so no direct support from them. But from our 3rd PartySupplier from which we got the Things the communication is ok for Longterm Support Things but if you just have a simple Question 2Weeks ore more is just to long.

Thats why i asked here because it is quicker.